# currency symbol on internet browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, formatting, currency

I'm having some problems with the currency symbol on some internet browser, specially Google Chrome (shocking right)

Trying my web site on the browsers, several of them (FireFox, Safari, Opera) displayed the web site currency symbol on Euros, my website is dedicated to Mexican users, hence i need the Mexican Peso Currency Symbol ($). On FireFox and Opera, it wasn't much of a hassle, i just needed to change the regional setting from Spanish-Spain to Spanish-Mexico, no sweet there, but there's is no option to do this on Safari and Chrome.

Whatever i found, they are telling to change the regional setting of my pc, but all the pc's i had tried and are showing the euro symbol are set to Mexico

Any idea on what can i do, to force the currency symbol?

Comment: How are you formatting the currency symbol? I usually use the following code and the $ symbol renders correctly in every browser `String.Format("${0}", this.Presupuesto.ToString("#,##0"))`

Comment: Chrome solved, now only Safari is giving me trouble

Comment: @daniloquio actually, we are giving the field/control a currency mask on runtime/client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change Google Chrome's language settings(which I believe will correct the currency sign issue) go to chrome://chrome/settings/ (its the settings link on my macbook pro) click on the link for advanced settings, and go to language settings, add the language you want, and drag it to the top of the stack making it the highest preference.

Comment: This doesn't help as there is no language option for "Spanish (Mexico)"

Comment: Is there any way to force a browser to use a specific currency format (ie: $ USD) for a site? Anything I can include in the head or otherwise?